# show and hide spinner with jquery : does not work on Iphone, safary etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, spinner, compatibility

I am trying to show / hide a spinner with JQuery. Basicaly I have this code :

```
function unLoader(e) {
    $(".site-content").hide();
    $(".loading").show();    
    }

   $(window).on('load', function() {
         $(".loading").hide();
         $(".site-content").show();
          window.onbeforeunload = unLoader;
    });
```

It works fine with Chrome and FireFox on Windows , on Chrome on MacOS.
But it does not work on Safari MacOS. It does not work on Safari Iphone or Chrome Iphone.

Trying to change the eventName does not resolve the problem :

```
var isOnIOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);    
var eventNameHide = isOnIOS ? "pagehide" : "beforeunload";
var eventNameShow = isOnIOS ? "pageshow" : "load";
```

Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your context the `$().on("load")` function is unclear. You can use document ready for check if document loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $(".loading").hide();
         $(".site-content").show();
          window.onbeforeunload = unLoader;
    });
```

and also if you want to use your actually code, you need to defined the pagehide method. Please try:

```
var isOnIOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);    
var eventNameHide = isOnIOS ? "pagehide" : "beforeunload";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".loading").hide();
    $(".site-content").show();
    window.addEventListener(eventNameHide, function (event) { 
        window.event.stopPropagation(); //trying with and without
        $(".site-content").hide();
        $(".loading").show(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: This code does not work on Safari MacOS, Chrome Iphone or Safari Iphone.

Comment: Ok. you need to show spinner on load page and after is loaded the spinner hide? correct?

Comment: I want to show the spinner when the page is loading. So, I show it before unloading the page the user is on, it displays while the new page is not shown. And when the new page is loaded, then the spinner should hide. Thanks

Comment: maybe i should use modernizr, or a polyfill, so that the spinner works on Safari, or Iphone ...
Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: I tried your code to show my spinner in Safari when leaving the page to go load a new page. But somehow the spinner is not showing. Keeping the spinner un-hidden makes the spinner show. So it is not the spinner itself that it the problem. Somehow `pagehide` is not responding in the `addEventListener`. Is there a workaround for this?